# Mysql: counter queries by users

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

I have a MySQL instance (hosted on google cloud managed solution) that giving service for multiple applications. Each application has its own MySQL-user.

In the administrator dashboard, I see that the number of queries is larger then I expected. So, I want to investigate which application consumes more resources then I expected.

Expected output, something like

```
Username    |    Queries
------------------------
User1       |    100
User2       |    100
...
```

Is this possible to get this information?

Comment: try to run "show processlist" on MySQL, is the given information enough?

Comment: `show processlist;` not presenting information about how many queries have been done. The only semi-relevant information is the `TIME` column, which you can see if the connection is sleeping or not...

Comment: It may be possible by querying `sys.dm_exec_sessions`. Take a look at this [thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/135078/how-to-get-history-of-queries-executed-with-username-in-sql). The accepted answer shows how to get the history of queries per user. You can make a variation of this and employing the use of `COUNT()` to make it fit with your use case.

Comment: @JKleinne This thread is not dealing with MySQL. I guess it SQL SERVER.

Comment: You can use [`user_summary`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sys-user-summary.html) in this case and get user statistics

Comment: Interesting @JKleinne. I didn't found any information on how to use it except the documentation on the attached link. Do you have an example?

Comment: You can try something along the lines of `SELECT user AS Username, statements AS Queries FROM sys.user_summary;`